# GPU Memory in Chrome Task Manager: GPU Process vs. Tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, three.js, webgl, chromium

While trying to debug a GPU memory leak in my Three.js app, i'm confused which value for the 'GPU Memory' column is relevant for my app:

The GPU Memory eaten by the GPU Process or the GPU Memory eaten by the tab, where my app is loaded?

Some cleaning up in my Three.js code definitely decreased the GPU Memory footprint of my tab in the Task Manager, but i suspect having another leak, which only impacts the footprint of the GPU process.

UPDATE:
Could the GPU Memory displayed in the row of my tab maybe be the share of the total GPU memory consumed by the GPU thread?

The relevant rows of my Chrome Task Manager
[image: The relevant rows of my Chrome Task Manager]